# Website's clock for Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Okay, here is the deal. When i look at to match clocks from my browser, for example it shows 14.00 but when i pull it with my python bot it gives me -1 clock, for example 13.00, my question is, how can i set python's clock for the region where i connect from? I mean, how can website set it's own clock for python.

Note: My clock is GMT +3 (Istanbul, Turkey)
Here is the webpage: hltv.org/matches
Here is my codes:

```
import datetime, requests, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

matchlinks_um = []

r = requests.get('http://hltv.org/matches')
sauce = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

for links in soup.find(class_="standard-headline", text=(datetime.date.today())).find_parent().find_all(
        class_="upcoming-match"):
    matchlinks_um.append('https://hltv.org' + links.get('href'))

for x in range(len(matchlinks_um)):
    r = requests.get(matchlinks_um[x])
    sauce = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

    a = soup.find('div', class_='time').text
    print(a)
```

Btw, if you have any suggestion for the title i can change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the correct time is renderd by js because if you disable the js in your brwser you'll  get the same results as with your python script.
Usually when parsing dynamic content the solution is `selenium` or similar clients, but in this case there is a unix timestamp in your tag's attruibutes (data-unix), which we can use to get the correct time.

```
import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://hltv.org/matches')
sauce = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

matchlinks_um = []

for links in soup.find(class_="standard-headline", text=(datetime.date.today())).find_parent().find_all(
        class_="upcoming-match"):
    matchlinks_um.append('https://hltv.org' + links.get('href'))

for link in matchlinks_um:
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    a = soup.find('div', class_='time')['data-unix']
    t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(a[:10])).time()
    print(t)
```

Note that `t` is a `datetime.time` object, but you could easily convert it to a string if you like.
Also when parsing html it's best to use [`.text`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) because it holds the decoded content.

---

But even if the tag had no 'data-unix' attribute, we could still get the correct time by adding one hour to the value of the tag's text with [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta). For example:

```
s = '15:30'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%H:%M') + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
t = dt.time()

print(t)
#16:30:00
```

- `s` is a string with value '15:30' (H:M format), like those we get from the website. When we pass this string to [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) we get a `datetime` object, so now we can add one hour with `timedelta`.
- `dt` is a `datetime` object with value `1900-01-01 16:30:00` (15:30 + 1 hour). By calling the [`.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) method we get a `datetime.time` object.
- `t` is a [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) object with value `16:30:00`. You could get the hour with `t.hour` (integer), or do more calculations or convert it to string or keep it as it is.
  The pont is that `t` is `s` + 1 hour.

---

About the 'data-unix' attribute, I don't know if it's a standard attribute (first time I see it), so I don't think you'll find it in any other websites.

Comment: Is it possible you to explain what have you done at variable t? (I mean can you explain code by code) and also i wonder what is that usage ['data-unix']? Under which cases i can use it? Can you leave a little note to answer or to here please? :) Thank you btw, im sure that is my answer.

Comment: @akagna I've tried to explain a little more, if you have any other questions please let me know.

Comment: I learned about timemodule and i understood very well about strptime and about how you manipulated date, i understood totally everything. Thanks for explaining. :) About data-unix, yes i saw this usage from you for the first time, still thanks. You are the man :D the Adam (means good, honest, upright man in Turkish)

Comment: Thank you for you kind words @akagna. I'm very glad I helped you gain new knowledge! Cheers!!

Comment: Hi @t.m.adam, hope you are doing fine. This is my last (without creating a post) ever request to you to help me solve an upload related issue. Although it seems I'm very close to solve it, I could not fix it even after trying for the last two days. This is the ***[file](https://filebin.net/ud6pr0zgo238zqdj)*** link. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @MITHU Sorry, I can't help. The post fields and cookies seem to be right, and the Referer and Origin headers are not important. I have no idea what the problem is and that's one of the reasons I advise you to ask a question, someone else should be able to help.